# unable to run docker compose showing error -bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was setting up .YML file using docker compose and found i have the latest docker compose version and not stable so I deleted the existing one using 
the command `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/docker-compose`

then i again tring and installing docker compose but showing this error

```
-bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How and where did you install your new `docker-compose` version? Could you paste the line you used to install? Is it in /usr/bin/docker-compose?